# Meaning of the blue time bar in Jenkins' Stage View plugin

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Does anyone knows how to interpret the blue bar in the stage view of the jenkins pipeline. It has definetely something to do with the times the stage consumes in different run, but what is the exact meaning and where is this feature documented?

Hopefully, anyone knows the answer to this question.

[image: Time bar for Stage View Plugin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official link](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-stage-view/):

When you have complex build Pipelines, it is useful to be able to see the progress of each stage. The Pipeline Stage View plugin includes an extended visualization of Pipeline build history on the index page of a flow project, under *Stage* View.

To take advantage of this view, you need to define stages in your flow. You can have as many stages as you like, in a linear sequence.

Each row also records the build number, date it was started, and any changelog entries from a version control system. *Progress bars also indicate how long each stage is taking and how long it might still be expected to take, based on historical averages*.

Comment: So, what's the meaning of the blue bar? Sorry, perhaps my English is not good enough, but I didn't find the answer in your text.

Comment: If there are let's say three builds (i.e., three rows) executed so far, then blue bar for any given stage will show the average time taken by that particular stage.

Comment: OK, I think I understand, I'll post another, graphical answer.

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while. A graphical explanation:

[image: A graphical explanation]